# Reversing a curve without reversing its text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to make a mirror image of a curve. Is it possible to avoid reversing the text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [very thick, red] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) node [red, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};

\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]
\draw [very thick, blue] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) node [blue, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could add just another `xscale=-1` to the node options and exploit the fact that minus times minus is plus. Or abandon `transform shape` and introduce appropriate signs in the shift(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-reverse the text, use `\scalebox{-1}[1]{$AS$}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [very thick, red] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) 
node [red, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};

\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]
\draw [very thick, blue] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) 
node [blue, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {\scalebox{-1}[1]{$AS$}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Either abandon `transform shape`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
\draw [very thick, red] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) node [red, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};

\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]
\draw [very thick, blue] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.]
+(42.:2.4cm) node [blue, xshift=-.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or add `xscale=-1` to the node options

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [very thick, red] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.] +(42.:2.4cm) node [red, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};

\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]
\draw [very thick, blue] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125, looseness=1.]
+(42.:2.4cm) node [blue, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm,xscale=-1] {$AS$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yield the same output as in [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448193/121799).