# Reversing a curve using mirror

Tags: tikz-pgf

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448192/reversing-a-curve-without-reversing-its-text), I've got answers to reverse a curve using `xscale=-1` or  `\scalebox{-1}[1]`.

I found that braces can be reversed using `mirror`, as in the following code. Can `mirror` be also used to reverse a curve?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [thick, red, decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3.5pt}, xshift=0pt, yshift=-.08cm] (1.2,1) -- +(-90:1.cm);
\draw [thick, blue, decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3.5pt, mirror}, xshift=0pt, yshift=-.08cm] (1,1) -- +(-90:1.cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [very thick, red] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125] +(42.:2.4cm) node [red, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm] {$AS$};
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]
\draw [very thick, blue] (.8,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125]
+(42.:2.4cm) node [blue, xshift=.4cm, yshift=.2cm,xscale=-1] {$AS$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why you not simple try?

Comment: I tried, but I could not figure out how to put the code.

Comment: @Hany Your `my mirror` would be a very simple thing *if* you would not do all these shifts which complicate things. Then `\tikzset{my mirror/.style={xscale=-1,every node/.append style={xscale=-1}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\draw [very thick, red] (-1.2,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125] +(42.:2.4cm) 
++ (0.4,0.2) node  {$AS$};
\begin{scope}[my mirror]
\draw [very thick, blue] (-1.2,-2.6) to [out=20,in=-125]
+(42.:2.4cm) ++ (0.4,0.2)node  {$AS$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}` would do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is not possible to use the option mirror in the \draw definition command, otherwise you would have thought of it.